Set row height of a cell based on text in cell
I have a column that contains contact information for businesses that has wrap text on and has 5-8 lines of text in some cells. I need to change the row height based on how much information a cell contains.
There are other cells in this column that I don't want anything done with.
Example target cell:
Some Business
123 Main St
Philadephia, PA  19007
W: (555)555-5555 
F: (555)555-5555
E: Business@business.com                                                                                                                      
WWW: Business@business.com

For all cells in this column from B3-Last Row
If contains "E:", set row height to 67
If contains "E:" and "F:", set row height to 80
If contains "E:", "F:", and "WWW:", set row height to 90
I attempted to use Instr, but I can't even get it to work for one letter.
Dim cell As Range, Finalrow2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str1, str2 As String

Finalrow2 = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ws.Range("B" & Finalrow2).Cells
    str1 = Range("B" & Finalrow2).Text
    str2 = "E:"
    With cell
        If InStr(str1, str2) > 0 Then
            .RowHeight = 70
        End If
    End With
Next cell


You need to define the complete range: For Each cell In ws.Range("B3:B" & Finalrow2).Cells

Btw, the .Cells is redundant.

str1 needs to be cell you're checking the same cell over and over again as it is now.

Another side note: Dim str1, str2 As String needs to be Dim str1 As String, str2 As String if you want both variables to be type String.

Thank you all, those tweaks got the desired result! So in reality, str1 doesn't need to exist?
